# Excluding some rows that exist on another table but also excludes rows between certain values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 2 tables:

Table A

```
Process  Type   SC  TC
AS         D     2  I
AS         D     2  C
AS         D     3  C
AS         D     2  X
AS         D     5  S
```

Table B

```
Process  Type   SC  TC Valid
AS         D     2  I   y
AS         D     2  C   y
```

Is it possible to exclude the row    " AS         D     3  C" without hard coding any values here. Or how can table B be rewritten for this case? I want to exclude that row since it is not valid on table B but also because it falls under the TC of "C". The last row in Table A is okay because there is nothing being validated with a TC of "S".

```
AS         D     2  I
AS         D     2  C
AS         D     2  X
AS         D     5  S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the query that may help to you and not using any hard code

```
    select distinct A.* from  A inner join  B on A.Process=B.Process 
    and A.Type =B.Type and A.SC=B.SC
    union
    select * from 
    (
    select distinct top 1 A.* from  A inner join  B on A.Process=B.Process 
    and A.Type =B.Type and A.SC!=B.SC
    where A.TC!=B.TC    
    order by sc desc
  ) as T
```

Query Output

```
Process     Type    SC  TC
AS           D       2  C
AS           D       2  I
AS           D       2  X
AS           D       5  s
```

here is fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bfa6/10

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work. In the first select you are joining TableA with TableB where `TC <> 'S'`, as you are not considering those rows when comparing against TableB and Second Select gets all those rows from TableA, where `TC = 'S'` , as you want them always.

```
SELECT a.Process, a.Type, a.SC, a.TC 
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.TC = b.TC AND a.SC = b.SC
WHERE a.TC <> 'S'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.Process, a.Type, a.SC, a.TC 
FROM TableA AS a
WHERE a.TC = 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the valid criteria of table A is

1. TC doesn't exist in table B
2. SC of Table A = Table B and Table B valid = 'y'

You can apply union to solve this

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (
SC INT,
TC VARCHAR(1)
)

DECLARE @B TABLE (
SC INT,
TC VARCHAR(1),
VALID VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @A SELECT 2,'I'
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 2,'C'
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 3,'C'
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 2,'X'
INSERT INTO @A SELECT 5,'S'
INSERT INTO @B SELECT 2,'I','Y'
INSERT INTO @B SELECT 2,'C','Y'

--QUERY
SELECT * FROM @A A LEFT OUTER JOIN @B B ON A.TC=B.TC AND B.VALID='Y'
WHERE A.SC = B.SC
UNION
SELECT * FROM @A A LEFT OUTER JOIN @B B ON A.TC=B.TC AND B.VALID='Y'
WHERE B.SC IS NULL 

--QUERY 2
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
SELECT A.* FROM @A A LEFT OUTER JOIN @B B ON A.TC=B.TC AND B.VALID='Y'
WHERE A.SC = B.SC
UNION
SELECT A.* FROM @A A LEFT OUTER JOIN @B B ON A.TC=B.TC AND B.VALID='Y'
WHERE B.SC IS NULL 
) AS V
```

Comment: I think this is pretty close to what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get just the first SC and TC columns that show up in that new query in those 4 rows?

Comment: added 1 more query to select the first sc & tc column shown in those 4 rows. Not sure if it is what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TableB B 
    WHERE A.TC = B.TC
        AND ( A.TC <> B.TC OR A.Type <> B.Type OR A.SC <> B.SC ))
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/107fe/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it's a bit difficult to understand what you are after exactly. It seems you want to exclude all `TC = 'C'`, except for entries found in table `B`.

With `WHERE NOT (tc = 'C' AND A not in B)` = `WHERE tc <> 'C' OR A in B` we get:

```
select * 
from a
where tc <> 'C'
or exists
(
  select *
  from b
  where b.process = a.process
  and b.type = a.type
  and b.sc = a.sc
  and b.tc = a.tc
)
order by process, type, sc, tc;
```

Admittedly this is a bit ugly in SQL Server. In many other DBMS we could replace the `EXISTS` clause with a mere `or (process, type, sc, tc) in (select process, type, sc, tc from b)`.

It is not clear what the `Valid` flag is for. Maybe you'll have to include the condition `valid = 'y'` in the subquery.